# Unresolved dependency in module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I get a $injector:unpr with the following code in AngularJs1.3,that I am unable to fathom.

index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="directivesApp">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS Directive example</title>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="directiveCtrl">
    <user-info user="MD"></user-info>
    <user-info user="VP"></user-info>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('directivesApp', [])
.controller("directiveCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.MD={ "firstName":"...","lastName":"..."};
    $scope.VP={"firstName":"...","lastName":"..."};
})
.directive("userInfo",function($scope){
    return{
    restrict:'E',
    template:'User : <b>{{user.firstName}}</b> <b>{{user.lastName}}</b>',
    scope:{user : "="}
    };
});
```

Help in resolving this is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope`, within a directive, is accessed via the `link` or `controller` method functions, and isn't injected at the top-level. Try this:

```
angular.module('directivesApp', [])
.controller("directiveCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.MD={ "firstName":"...","lastName":"..."};
    $scope.VP={"firstName":"...","lastName":"..."};
})
.directive("userInfo",function(){
    return{
    restrict:'E',
    link: function (scope) { 
      // Scope using code here... 
    },
    template:'User : <b>{{user.firstName}}</b> <b>{{user.lastName}}</b>',
    scope:{user : "="}
    };
});
```

[Here's a Codepen.](http://codepen.io/andRyanMiller/pen/gpgzaw) Hope this helps!

Comment: Trick was to remove scope from the .directive("userInfo",function($scope) - as you hinted.